# Image file memory usage grows when switching tabs

Tags: .net, memory

I'm working with a .net application that allows users to load an image on one tab and then switch to another tab to make notes.  The idea is to not clear the image when navigating away from the tab so that users can toggle back and forth with ease.  The problem I am running into is when switching back to the tab that contains the image, virtual and physical memory grows as if it's opening the image again.  GC does get executed after a period of time however there are users that will switch between tabs several times in the matter of a minute or 2.  Without clearing the image, is there any way to prevent the memory usage from growing?

Load Image

```
    private void LoadImage(int imageId, MountPoint mountPoint, MountPoint srcMountPoint)
    {
        if (mountPoint == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mountPoint));

        var imgSrc = _imageSvc.GetItemForImageId(imageId);
        if (imgSrc == null) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(imageId));

        try
        {

            string filename = string.Empty;

            bool found = false;
            foreach (var dir in _imageDirs)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dir)) continue;
                filename = Path.Combine(dir, imgSrc.ImagePath);
                if (File.Exists(filename))
                {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!found) throw new LoadImageException("Image not found.");

            mountPoint.Image = null;
            if (srcMountPoint?.Image != null)
                mountPoint.Image = new Image(srcMountPoint.Image);
            else mountPoint.Image = _imageIo.LoadImage(filename);

            var rawImg = Path.ChangeExtension(filename, "raw");
            if (!File.Exists(rawImg)) _imageIo.SaveImage(mountPoint.Image, rawImg);

            mountPoint.Context = new ImageContext
            {
                ImageId = imgSrc.ImageId,
                SavePointId = imgSrc.SavePointID,
                Filename = filename,
                Date = imgSrc.CreatedDate,
                Teeth = mountPoint.Sequence > 0
                    ? mountPoint.ToothPositions.AsEnumerable().Select(_ => _.ToString()).ToList()
                    : (imgSrc.Teeth?.SanitizeDbList() ?? string.Empty).Split(',').ToList(),
                TakenBy = imgSrc.TakenBy
            };
            mountPoint.Title = ((ImageContext)mountPoint.Context).Title;

            var annFile = Path.ChangeExtension(filename, "ann");
            if (File.Exists(annFile)) _annIo.LoadContainer(mountPoint.AnnotationContainer, annFile);

            _events.GetEvent<ImageLoadedEvent>().Publish(new ImageLoadedEventArgs(imgSrc.ImageId));
        }
        catch (LoadImageException ex)
        {
            mountPoint.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
            _events.GetEvent<ImageLoadedEvent>().Publish(new ImageLoadedEventArgs(imgSrc.ImageId));
        }
    }
```

Tab change

```
    private void OnTabChanged(Tabs tab)
    {
        _currentModule?.Dispose();

        _currentModule = NavigatorModule.Create(tab);
        CurrentView = _currentModule?.CreateView() ?? null;
        if (_currentView !=null) _currentView.DataContext = _currentModule;
        if (_currentModule !=null) _currentModule.IsActive = true;
    }
```

I set a breakpoint at the LoadImage method and only gets hit when loading the image the first time.  It does not get hit when switching between tabs.

On the tab change, I added some code to dispose but that did not do the trick.  I also tried forcing garbage collection but that did not work either.

Comment: Sounds like something is reloading the image each time and not disposing it. Are you doing this in the `Paint` event? Please show code

Comment: I thought maybe it wasn't getting disposed as well but the code shows that it's in the base class of the model where the image is being loaded.  That said, there are no paint events, the app is actually using lead tools to handle image files which I'm wondering may have an issue.  Currently going through the code and trying a few things.  Will show code if what I try doesn't do the trick.  Thanks